# How can I find the serial number on a mac programmatically from the terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal, hardware, command-line, serial-number

What command can I use to retrieve the system's serial number from the unix command line? As `uname` will output some information about the software and hardware, I would like to retrieve the serial number from a command to use in a script.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The [system_profiler](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/system_profiler.8.html) command provides a direct answer that’s easily human readable (assuming you are on 10.3 or newer), but you can also use [ioreg](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/ioreg.8.html) for the task as it generally completes faster.

`system_profiler SPHardwareDataType` is the data type that contains the core hardware information, and you can use grep or awk to pare things down further as needed:

```
system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | awk '/Serial/ {print $4}'
```

or

```
ioreg -l | awk '/IOPlatformSerialNumber/ { print $4;}'
```

Both of those commands take between 0.5 and 0.2 seconds to run on modern SSD Macs, so if you want to [optimize the command](https://gist.github.com/chilcote/9b5f46ac6fdb801633e4) and [remove the "](https://twitter.com/pmbuko/status/563051228444504064) you can have your answer in 0.005s or so:

```
ioreg -c IOPlatformExpertDevice -d 2 | awk -F\" '/IOPlatformSerialNumber/{print $(NF-1)}'
```

Answer (score 18):

This also works…

```
ioreg -l | grep IOPlatformSerialNumber
```

Answer (score 4):

C++ example from https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn1103/_index.html:

```
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
#include <IOKit/IOKitLib.h>

std::string 

getSerialNumber()

{

   CFStringRef serial;
    char buffer[32] = {0};
    std::string seriaNumber;

io_service_t platformExpert = IOServiceGetMatchingService(kIOMasterPortDefault,
                                                          IOServiceMatching("IOPlatformExpertDevice"));
if (platformExpert)
{
    CFTypeRef serialNumberAsCFString = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(platformExpert,
                                                                       CFSTR(kIOPlatformSerialNumberKey),
                                                                       kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);
    if (serialNumberAsCFString) {
        serial = (CFStringRef)serialNumberAsCFString;
    }
    if (CFStringGetCString(serial, buffer, 32, kCFStringEncodingUTF8)) {
        seriaNumber = buffer;
    }

    IOObjectRelease(platformExpert);
}
return seriaNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This works in Python 3.10.5 on macOS

```py
import json
import os
import time

# Example MySPHardwareDataType.json created and used by this script
#{
#  "SPHardwareDataType" : [
#    {
#      "_name" : "hardware_overview",
#      "activation_lock_status" : "activation_lock_disabled",
#      "boot_rom_version" : "7459.121.3",
#      "chip_type" : "Apple M1",
#      "machine_model" : "MacBookPro17,1",
#      "machine_name" : "MacBook Pro",
#      "number_processors" : "proc 8:4:4",
#      "os_loader_version" : "7459.121.3",
#      "physical_memory" : "16 GB",
#      "platform_UUID" : "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX",
#      "provisioning_UDID" : "XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
#      "serial_number" : "XXXXXXXXXXXX"
#    }
#  ]
#}

def export_basic_hwinfo_to_json(json_filename_and_path):
    
    # This is the command that will execute.  It will run macOS' built-in
    # system_profiler binary, filtered to only show the contents of 
    # SPHardwareDataType, which contains the data we are looking for.
    # Additionally, we have also specified that it should be exported to JSON
    # format, and that standard output should be redirected to the file specified earlier
    command = "system_profiler SPHardwareDataType -json >" + json_filename_and_path
    
    # execute the command
    os.popen(command)
    
    # This loop waits for the file to exist before continuing
    while os.path.exists(json_filename_and_path) is False:
        time.sleep(1)
    
    
def get_serial(json_filename_and_path) -> str:
    # open the .json file for processing
    file_handle = open(json_filename_and_path)
    
    # load the contents of the .json file into a Python dictionary
    hw_info_dict = json.load(file_handle)
    
    # retrieve the data we are looking for
    serial = hw_info_dict['SPHardwareDataType'][0]['serial_number']
    return serial

    
def get_machine_sku(json_filename_and_path) -> str:
    # open the .json file for processing
    file_handle = open(json_filename_and_path)
    
    # load the contents of the .json file into a Python dictionary
    hw_info_dict = json.load(file_handle)
    
    # retrieve the data we are looking for
    machine_sku = hw_info_dict['SPHardwareDataType'][0]['machine_model']
    return machine_sku


def get_model(json_filename_and_path) -> str:
    # open the .json file for processing
    file_handle = open(json_filename_and_path)
    
    # load the contents of the .json file into a Python dictionary
    hw_info_dict = json.load(file_handle)
    
    # retrieve the data we are looking for
    model = hw_info_dict['SPHardwareDataType'][0]['machine_name']
    return model


def main():
    
    # We are going to store the output file in a temp directory
    temp_dir: str = os.environ.get('TMPDIR')
    temp_dir: str = temp_dir[:-1]
    
    json_filename: str = "MySPHardwareDataType.json"
    
    # Cleanly append the name of the output file to the file path
    json_filename_and_path: str = os.sep.join([temp_dir, json_filename])
    
    export_basic_hwinfo_to_json(json_filename_and_path)
    
    serial: str = get_serial(json_filename_and_path)
    machine_sku: str = get_machine_sku(json_filename_and_path)
    model: str = get_model(json_filename_and_path)

    print(F"serial={serial}")
    print(F"machine_sku={machine_sku}")
    print(F"model={model}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

To make it easier to remember, use a case insensitive search:

```
ioreg -l | grep -i serialnumber | grep -i platform
```

Comment: Warning: this returns a line
    |   "IOPlatformSerialNumber" = "YourSerialNumber"
That’s fine visually but if you use it in a script you'll need to pipe it to awk.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to count columns you can rely on the fact that the value is always in the last one and use

```sh
system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | awk '/Serial/{print $NF}'
```

Comment: gee, thanks mom @nohillside; we wouldn't want to subject people to anything that isn't kid gloves and kudos, you know, like reality.

Comment: SE works a bit different than forum sites. The way to give kudos is to upvote posts you like or which helped you.

Comment: I wasnt giving kudos @nohillside, I was criticizing the members of the thread that managed to waste time and misinform by discussing benchmarks around ioreg and system_profiler, giving weight to something that NO ONE outside of exceptional circumstances will ever concern themselves with. My beef, is that one day a junior ops engineer, will point to this or something like it, when defending a pull request that "optimizes" the serial-number-as-a-rube-goldberg-service, which is famously held together with spit and tape. Maybe balancing the carrot with the stick will help lead to less of that.

Comment: Please have a look at https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer for what we look for in answers. Also, this is a Q&A site not a forum, answers should stand on their own and not discuss other answers. If you want to discuss or criticize other answers, please use comments beneath that answer or the chat.

Answer (score 0):

It's potentially slightly cleaner to use the XML output of ioreg rather than parsing the human-readable form with sed/awk:

```
ioreg -c IOPlatformExpertDevice -d 2 -a | xmllint --xpath "/plist/dict[key='IORegistryEntryChildren']/array/dict/key[.='IOPlatformSerialNumber']/following-sibling::string[1]/node()" -
```