# How can i get the mac family number using terminal?

Tags: macos, terminal

I want to get model number/family number.

http://www.everymac.com/systems/by_capability/mac-specs-by-model-number-family-number.html.

I have found the above link that have listed all the Model number.

That information does not exist in the SystemProfiler.

Comment: *If* it's okay for you to not get the Model number directly (i.e. you get the Name/identifier and still have to reverse look up the Model number), then there's already a question with good answers [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/98080/can-a-macs-model-year-be-determined-via-terminal-command)

Answer (score 1):

Click the apple icon in the top left "About This Mac", admittedly not Terminal. Do you have any reason to do this in Terminal?

Comment: Yes I am doing the mac application. I want to get it programatically