# "About this Mac" showing wrong year

Tags: system-information

I bought a new 15" retina MBP earlier this year, with the discrete GPU M370X that was released this year. However, "About this Mac" claims that it's a Mid 2014 model. Is it just a glitch or does anyone else have the same info? It's nothing to worry about, right?

[image]

Comment: Where did you buy it from?

Comment: Bought it from the Apple Online store.

Comment: You should do a better job of hiding your serial number. I can make out most of the characters.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems to be a localization bug. Changing the system language to English reports the correct year.

Apple's website and the script bmike linked below return the correct year.

**Edit:** In MacOS 10.12 (Sierra), it now shows the correct year when Swedish is set as the primary language.

Answer (score 2):

I'd be curious what you find by plugging the last 4 of the serial number into this script: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/98089/5472 I've known cases where the serial number was encoded improperly and you'd need to collect your invoice/shipping document and contact the vendor or Apple to make sure you got the hardware for which you paid.

Apple does identify models by the year in which it was originally released. If you walk into an Apple Store and buy a Mac Pro that was made last week, you will still see that it's a 2013 model since they haven't updated that platform since then.

```
$ curl -s http://support-sp.apple.com/sp/product?cc=F693 | sed 's|.*<configCode>\(.*\)</configCode>.*|\1|'  
Mac Pro (Late 2013)
```

I would guess that you have nothing to worry about and that the marketing number wasn't bumped when your model specifications were upgraded. Especially since you are tracking the GPU, it's unlikely you have a wrong model. If you're really worried, get an `ioreg` and `sysdiagnose` and full system information dump to Apple Support and have them verify in writing that you were sold the proper model.

A visit to the genius bar (if convenient) might be the fastest way to have someone look up the service manual and check things since you wouldn't need to send any files in and could get an immediate answer.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer, but luckily the answer was much simpler (see my answer).

Comment: @pg-robban Bonus. Some XML file or JSON document that feeds the web site must have an error or typo... Glad to help.

Comment: The site reports the correct year. So it's a typo in the localization of the OS files somewhere.

Comment: Crazy - this backs up my theory that "Anything you can imagine that might go wrong, you will eventually find that issue in a shipping Apple product" - chalk one up for @pg-robban