# No version model of Macbook in 'About This Mac' section

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, hardware, serial-number

What does it mean if there is no version model?

[image]

Is it normal? I expect the money year after the words "MacBook Air" similar to this.

[image]

I would like to buy this particular Mac, should I worry about it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not normal, but it might be nothing. The next reinstall of the OS or an update might populate that field for you.

As far as I can tell, some time during installation the OS checks with Apple and downloads a localized string to represent the hardware. Since you're not US - perhaps there was an outage or an error localizing the string.

Unless there's other cause for concern - you could try reinstalling the OS - choose US location and language to see if that's related. Try looking up the serial number using the answer of the last link (The Stack Overflow question).

http://support-sp.apple.com/sp/product?cc=G940&lang=en_US

In your case, that's reported as a **MacBook Air (13-inch, Early 2015)** and you could change the language code to get a localized version.

Some other reading on serial numbers and the OS:

- [What causes a Mac to lose its serial number?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/77482/)
- [How can I find the serial number on a mac programmatically from the terminal?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40243/)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058151/how-does-system-profiler-retrieve-the-full-mac-hardware-identifier

Answer (score -2):

Did I understand correctly that you want the Mac Model identifier? It is found in the hardware overview. That is one levelbdown from your image.